# How can I Read Dynamic String and Store each key string Value into a varaible?

Tags: c#

This is my dynamic String:

```
String a= "SourceFilePath:C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\Anuj Tamrakar Working Folder, BackUpFilePath:C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\installer, SyncPath:C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\PSI, Password:3SMpUGoJpIJdWwRDXau+OQ==, NumberOfTimes:2, Time0:10:10 AM, Time1:10:10 PM"
```

I need to read the contents of the string and need to store each key and its coressponding values into variable. I need Output like

```
var SourceFilePath = "C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\Anuj Tamrakar Working Folder";
var BackUpFilePath="C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\installer"
var SyncPath="C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\PSI"
var Password="3SMpUGoJpIJdWwRDXau+OQ=="
var NumberOfTimes=2
var Time0=10:10 AM
var Time1=10:10 PM
```

This Part is Dynamic one:

```
var NumberOfTimes:2
var Time0:10:10 AM
var Time1:10:10 PM
```

If I have `NumberOfTimes:4` on my String File. I would Have 4 Time values i.e. Time0,Time1,Time2 and Time3. So i need to store these 4 time values into 4 variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in a console app and works fine. Below is my solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String a = @"SourceFilePath:C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\Anuj Tamrakar Working Folder, BackUpFilePath:C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\installer, SyncPath:C:\Users\Anuj\Desktop\PSI, Password:3SMpUGoJpIJdWwRDXau+OQ==, NumberOfTimes:2, Time0:10:10 AM, Time1:10:10 PM";

        Dictionary<string, string> processedString = ProcessString(a);

        //Here you can set the values to variable accessing it from the Dictionary
        var SourceFilePath = processedString["SourceFilePath"];
        var BackUpFilePath = processedString["BackUpFilePath"];
        var SyncPath = processedString["SyncPath"];
        var Password = processedString["Password"];
        var NumberOfTimes = Convert.ToInt32(processedString["NumberOfTimes"]);

        // And for the dynamic variables like Time01, Time02 I recommend you to create a list which holds all the time components.
        // Because creating a variable on the fly will be more complex for your requirement and is not necessary at this moment.
        //So you can do this
        var TimeComponents = processedString.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("Time")).Select(x => x).ToList();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

And the process of splitting up the string and creating a dictionary is as below.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ProcessString(string toProcess)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> processedString = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var eachSubString = toProcess.Split(',');

        foreach (var subStr in eachSubString)
        {
            var keyValue = subStr.Trim().Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
            processedString.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        }

        return processedString;
    }
```

And here is the screen shot of the debugger

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Reddy :) It Worked

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary object.

Split string input on , then loop through variable key value pairs splitting on :.
Store key and value in dictionary.

You don't need to declare each variable but you could look it up in the dictionary by the key.

Answer (score 0):

It must be something like below.

```
  // you can also fill an array dynamically
 var NumberOfTimes=["10:10 AM","10:11 AM","10:12 AM"]
 //count of stored items in array
 NumberOfTimes.length
 //in order to print or use in some where else
 NumberOfTimes.forEach(function(e,i){
 //do somethings
 });
```